# What happens when a maximally entangled state passes through a $k$-extendible channel?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, symmetry, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

In the context of Phys. Rev. A 104, 022401 ([arXiv:1803.10710](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10710)), Figure 3

1. What happens when a maximally entangled state( not $k$ extendible even for $k=2$) passes through a $k$-extendible channel? We know that a $k$ extendible channel preserves $k$ extendible states.
2. What role do $k$ extendible channels play in entanglement transmission? Are we using these channels in entanglement transmission only because they are free channels in the resource theory of $k$ unextendibility? or does it give us some advantage when we use these channels?

Comment: Please focus on question, or make clear why they are closely enough related. Also, it would help if you have a little bit of context or background. Also, why does "We know that a  extendible channel preserves  extendible states." hold? Isn't the channel which replaces everything by the identity infinitely extendible (if I have the correct definition in mind)?